# Refresh Grid with new DataContext WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, datasource, domainservices

I have a grid with a domain service binded to the data context. I would like to refresh that data context.

I have the code:

```
            <Grid DataContext="{Binding Data, ElementName=userDomainDataSource}" Name="gridAccountDetails">
                <sdk:Label Content="Address Line" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="443,67,0,0" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="537,59,0,0" x:Name="txtAccountDetailsAddress" Text="{Binding addressline, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, TargetNullValue='', ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" Width="233" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" DataContext="{Binding}" />
                <sdk:Label Content="County" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="443,142,0,143" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" />
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="537,134,0,143" x:Name="txtAccountDetailsCounty" Text="{Binding county, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, TargetNullValue='', ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" Width="233" />
                <sdk:Label Content="Email" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,143,0,142" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment, Height" />
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,136,0,142" x:Name="txtAccountDetailsEmail" Text="{Binding email, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, TargetNullValue='', ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" Width="233" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" />

                <sdk:Label Content="First Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,67,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,60,0,0" x:Name="txtAccountDetailsFirstname" Text="{Binding firstname, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" Width="233" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" />

                <sdk:Label Content="Last Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,104,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,97,0,0" x:Name="txtAccountDetailsLastname" Text="{Binding lastname, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, TargetNullValue='', ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" Width="233" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" />
                <sdk:Label Content="Postcode" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="443,0,0,104" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="537,0,0,104" x:Name="txtAccountDetailsPostcode" Text="{Binding postcode, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, TargetNullValue='', ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" Width="233" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                <sdk:Label Content="Town" Margin="0,105,323,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="537,0,0,180" x:Name="txtAccountDetailsTown" Text="{Binding town, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, TargetNullValue='', ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" Width="233" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                <Button Content="Edit Account Details" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,26,35" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="136"/>
            </Grid>
```

I have set the domain source with the code:

```
EntityQuery<Web.User> qry =
                    from u in usrClass.getQuery()
                    where u.userId == usrClass.getUserId()
                    select u;
                LoadOperation<Web.User> loadU = usrClass.loadUsersQuery(qry);
                userDomainDataSource.DataContext = loadU.Entities;
```

I have tried using:

```
gridAccountDetails.DataContext = userDomainDataSource.DataContext;
```

and

```
gridAccountDetails.DataContext = userDomainDataSource.Data;
```

with no luck

But I would like to refresh the datasource so the new values get put into the textboxes, as these can be changed by the user.

Can anyone provide any information. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have to tell "gridAccountDetails" that the "Data" of "userDomainDataSource" changed. Most widely used for this is to raise a PropertyChanged event altough I'm not sure how this would fit with your service, possibly consider a buffer from the service to your Grid.

One more thing once binded I wouldn't touch the datacontext of your Grid, you're binding it and then overwriting.

Comment: I can't seem to find a propertyChanged event, looking in visual studio it isn't listed.

Comment: I would create a custom class (little wrapper) and use it for binding. Implement INotifyPropertyChanged and it should work. I just noticed the silverlight tag - I'm not sure if that would work with silverlight as I have no experience in it. I am writing only about wpf.